# How to join two tables without a relationship, taking only one value from a table and pasting it to the other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

Table_A:

[image]

I want to take the Min of date from Table_B, and paste it to Table_A. Like the following:

[image]

I cannot figure out a way to do this. The only thing which is close is a cross_join, which is not what I want. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a subquery:

```
select name, revenue,
    (select min(date) from table_b) as date
from table_a
```

Referring to the end of your question, note that this is a `cross join` in essence. We could very well phrase the query as:

```
select a.name, a.revenue, b.date
from table_a a
cross join (select min(date) as date from table_b) b
```